# How to acquire extracted directory using pyUnrar2?

Tags: python, rar, unrar

I'm using pyUnrar2 to batch extract rar files, what I would like to acquire is the name of the directory that the files reside in once extracted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract path is set as an argument to `extract()`.

If an archive have its own parent directory, you can grab it by using `infolist()`:

```
import UnRAR2

rarc = UnRAR2.RarFile('test.rar')
list = rarc.infolist()

if list[0].isdir:
    print 'Parent directory in archive: %r' % list[0].filename
```